# Why wont Lucene index/search for '-' character....?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Im having real problems with Lucene. Iv'e got to find a bug in lots of code and I just cant work out what the problem is. Basically we have some code in the global.asax file and it creats the index. Then we have some code that searches is. Im just not able to tell whether its the searching code or the indexing code which is the problem. Is there any way I can open up the index to see whether it will accept '-' characters?

Comment: Try [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) to inspect & test your index.

Comment: Make sure you use the same Analyzer when you index and when you search

Comment: Might also consider asking on the lucene-net-user mailing list http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/community.html